# How to delete the folder that contains your code python

Tags: python, directory, delete-file, shutil

I have a folder that inside I have my code along other files.
I want to delete this folder and all of it's content.

I tried using
`shutil.rmtree(path,ignore_errors=True)`
**path = path to the dir that is holding the file**
at first , however while the files were being deleted, the folder stays intact as well as it seems that it doesn't even delete the contents of the folder if you turn the file into exe.

I also tried using :

```py
for file in os.listdir(path):
        os.remove(os.path.join(path, file))
    os.rmdir(path)
```

**path = path to the the code file**
But it also didn't work and seems to be stuck.

Because I use relative path (__ file __), I get the wrong path and work on the TEMP directory and not the file's directory.

Am I missing something?

Comment: _... if you turn the file into exe_, how do you create the exe ? What is `path` ?

Comment: I used pyinstaller to turn the py code into exe